# LetsEncrypt and other CA mixed in Apache2.2 "overlap"

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, sni

seems like i can't get another SSL-Certificate on my maschine running.

I work on an Apache 2.2 and we got a domain with an SSLCertificate, signed by GlobalSign. Now i wanted to add another certificate (letsEncrypt) for another domain on the same maschine. (SNI)

To do so, i followed the intructions on the website and made a cert using
certbot certonly -manual
on another maschine and put them on my webserver.

There i changed the ports.conf from apache and added `NameVirtualHost *:433` and changed the VirtualHost-Statement of the sites/available/default-ssl from `_default_:433` to `*:433`.

Then i added the SSL-vHost to the config file of the new domain

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:433>

ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.org
DocumentRoot /var/www/newdomain/html
ServerName domain.org
ServerAlias www.domain.org

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/chain.pem

 #Setting goes here

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

When i run `apache2ctl configtest` i still get

```
[Fri Mar 31 15:55:37 2017] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 433, the first has precedence
```

Why? When i try to visit the new Domain over https, they show me that the Browser still gets the old GlobalSign-Cert which is for a completly different domain and thus not accepted:

```
 domain.org uses an invalid security certificate. 
 The certificate is only valid for the following names: signeddomainsiown.org 
 Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN
```

I get it, that there must be somewhere an entry which "comes first" and the server sends the wrong cert, or the chain is wrong, but how can I fix this?
I already grep'd for other *default* entries in my config, but didnt found anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use two separate SSL certificates on a same apache instance. The reason being that NameVirtualHost configurations are looked up after establishing the connection with the webserver, in this case via SSL on port 443. For this, it picks up first configured certificate, since it won't have host information before connection setup.

In your case, you have to use single SSL certificate for both domains, but get the certificate which can be used for multiple domain names. It is commonly referred as SAN (Subject Alternate Name) certificate in which we can add multiple domains (normally up to 10)